# Differential Form in Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Can a function $f(x,y,z)$ be a closed form?

I know that a function $f(x,y,z)$ is a $0-$form and the derivative of a constant is automatically zero. But how do I show that this is a closed form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, $df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} dz$, so if $f$ is constant, then its three partial derivatives are everywhere $0$, and this differential form $df$ is then obviously everywhere $0$ as well.  Thus, $f$ is a closed form.

Comment: can we conclude that the function is exact since it is closed?

Comment: No.  Exact implies closed, but closed does not imply exact.  Besides, only the zero function is exact.  This is because functions are 0-forms, and for them to be exact, would mean that they would be images under d of (-1)-degree forms, all of which are 0.

Comment: that makes sense. So what would be an example of a function $f(x,y,z)$ which is a $0-$form?

Comment: All smooth functions are 0-forms.